# Was this question incorrectly closed? Should it be reopened?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked this question:

- [Learning Python from Ruby; Differences and Similarities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769004/learning-python-from-ruby-differences-and-similarities)

Some people felt that it was "Not a Real Question" and closed it.

1. If I continue to disagree with their assessment, should I vote to re-open it? As the biased OP, I feel hesitant to do so.
2. Should this question be closed? Look at the quality of the responses. Look how we appear to be nearing in on completely covering the set of reasonable differences.

I understand that there is a greyscale continuum between a question that can clearly be answered versus one that can clearly never be answered. I feel that my question is quite close to the "can be answered", and I feel that the answers bear this out. But perhaps I am looking for something different in terms of an answer than others would like to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it has been closed is likely due to the idea that there are *innumerable* differences between the two languages.  One can choose to hit the top ten differences, the top 100 differences, or the top 1,000 differences and still never fully enumerate the problem space your question opens.

Personally, I think it can be a valuable and useful contribution to the community, but only if it's tightly controlled in terms of scope.  Consider modifying the question to tighten the focus.

Comment: Other than suggesting a limit to the number of differences, do you have any suggestions on how to tighten the focus?

Comment: @Phrogz - I'd suggest choosing one smaller aspect of the system, such as variables, and asking a more pointed question.  For instance, "How does program flow and control structures differ between Ruby and Python?"  Should elicit a much shorter, concise listing of differences in how functions are implemented, if/while/for/etc control structures are written, etc.  It's still a very large question, and you may want to restrict it to just functions, or just control loops, or just message passing, but it may last longer.  I think you'll get a much better understanding going this route anyway.

Comment: I agree, the internet is littered with lists like this which of course go out of date as new language features are added. As you say, pointed questions about specific tasks are far more valuable. e.g. what's the equivalent Ruby meta-programming concept XXX in Python.

Answer (score 4):

If you continue to disagree then vote to reopen.

I think it was closed correctly. There isn't much question there.